# .NET 5 Project returns 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, iis, .net-5, asp.net5

I have a web api project that I have prepared with .net 5. I want to publish this project on iis. but I am getting an error like the following;

{"Message":"Internal Server Error","StatusCode":500}

- .net 5 is installed on the server.
- I also installed the .net 5 hosting bundle package.

note: I can install visual studio on the same server and run the project without any problems. I'm facing this problem when I just want to publish and publish.

My publish settings are as follows.

- config:release
- target framework: .net 5
- deployment mode: framework-dependent
- target runtime: win-x64

---

In addition, I get a log like the one below from IIS, but I couldn't understand what it means.

```
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 10.0
```

#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2021-06-22 17:34:46
#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) cs(Referer) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
2021-06-22 17:34:46 ::1 GET / - 8080 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/91.0.4472.106+Safari/537.36 - 500 0 0 1178
2021-06-22 17:34:46 ::1 GET /favicon.ico - 8080 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/91.0.4472.106+Safari/537.36 http://localhost:8080/ 500 0 0 6

I will be grateful if you could help me.

Comment: You need the server logs to see details about the 500. It should have some more details to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ancm-diagnostics.html Run a report to rule out common mistakes, and then check if you have handled unhandled exceptions properly.

Comment: I added service logs. please check you again?